# Where did I find this organization scheme?

Tags: vimrc

Some time ago, I organized my `vimrc` in a particular way, modeling it after what I am pretty sure I remember to be one of the documents in the `:help`. But I've looked for an hour now and can't seem to find it. I did find this [github gist](https://gist.github.com/shm05/1799cc4b2cf7ef750d8e74f7f6cae9c2) that appears to have come from the same place.

Would someone be able to look at [my configuration file](https://github.com/mdebusk/dotfiles/blob/main/.vim/vimrc) and tell me where I might find the doc I used for its model?

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt help has anything with regards to "modeling" vimrc in this particular way. Please clarify what exactly is the model in your case? Folding with markers, to have arbitrary folded sections in a file?

Comment: @MaximKim Is the word "model" bothersome to you somehow? Because I can change it to something else.

Comment: I don't see it as a model or modeling, that is why I put it into quotes, but it has nothing to do how you see it yourself, so no need to change it to something else.

Comment: @MaximKim Well, now I'm curious. Because a model is "an example used to imitate," I'm wondering what you consider to be a model.

Comment: @MDeBusk Post your update about `:options` as an answer instead of an edit, since it actually addresses the question itself. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and welcome to [vi.se]! 

Comment: @filbranden Thank you, I did. And thank you for the welcome! I'm liking it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remembered! And it's obvious, too.

`:options`

For sake of my future reference and that of others, I've posted it here, neatly formatted:

[vimrc options as of version 9.0 patch 1](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2363634)

Answer (score 4):

Everybody has their own configuration of vimrc (or vim settings in general).

There is an approach to have every setting in a single file (`.vimrc`) as in your case, where one might think of logical partioning of the settings into sections using folding with `set foldmethod=marker`.

Other people might use vim runtime routines to split it into different files instead of having huge vimrc, e.g. filetype specific settins go to their own `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/some_ft_file.vim` file or more generic functions/settings go to some `~/.vim/plugin/settings_for_term.vim` or `~/.vim/plugin/arbitrary_name.vim` files.

Having said that, vim doesn't force you to do any of that and `:help` doesn't have anything (afaik) related to the "model" you showed us in both gist and your `.vimrc`.

Comment: I'm aware that `:help` doesn't have it. But I could **swear** I remember yanking it from some `:help` file and pasting it into a buffer before spending an hour or so moving stuff from my old, haphazardly-created `vimrc` to it.

I was new to vim at the time. When I'm new at something, I find that imposing some sort of order on things helps me think about it and get help when I need it. The structure I imposed on my `vimrc` did that for me.

Comment: There is a possibility that somebody has created a separate help file (I have my own by the way for various things) and you got it somehow and copy/pasted this info out of it.